# Reducing Virtual memory Page File Size on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, virtual-memory, pagefile

I've upgraded my PC to 16GB RAM and I've noticed the page file is at 16GB as well. Since I decided to go SSD, hard drive space is a bit limited so I would like to try and claim some of that 16GB back.

I've read plenty of articles that strongly advice against disabling the Paging file completely, however I was wondering if it was OK to reduce the size of the page file down to, say, a fixed size of 1GB? Is there any harm in doing this? Lets assume I'll never reach that 16GB RAM limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand how windows memory works.  [My answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/74822/how-do-i-tell-if-my-windows-server-is-swapping/75027#75027) give you that information.  If you don't care about memory dumps when windows crashes you can reduce the pagefile to your normal working set.