# Using Perfmon on Windows Server 2008 R2 Which counter value should be used for physical memory usage?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance-monitoring, memory-usage, perfmon, performance-counters

I am attempting to use Performance Monitor to set up a relevant User Defined Dataset on a Windows 2008 R2 Server. This is to track the performance costs incurred by an application that my team is developing.

One of the criteria I would like to track is the overall physical memory usage as the application runs. Within the dialog to add counters to the Dataset I see a **PhysicalDisk** category, and within that different counter values, but no **%Free Space**, value, which I believe is what I need.

I apologize for my light hardware knowledge, but which counter value should I be watching to track the physical memory usage and page swapping that may be occurring?

Comment: PhysicalDisk:%Free Space != Memory utilization. You're probably looking for something like Process:Private Bytes or Process:Working Set - Private for the actual process.

Comment: Yeah - disk isn't RAM (in most cases.)

Comment: Is Process: Working set equivalent to the physical memory that has been allocated for the concerned process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [How do I tell if my Windows server is swapping?](https://serverfault.com/questions/74822/how-do-i-tell-if-my-windows-server-is-swapping/75027#75027) .  In general the thing to worry about is the working set of the application.  You want to ensure that the working set will fit in ram without having to force other applications to start to page fault.    Windows doesn't allocate physical ram directly to an application.  (there are ways to effectively do that but it usually impacts application performance since you are bypassing the ability of windows to do memory management.