# What's the difference between Memory\Pool Paged Bytes and Process(_Total)\Paged Pool Bytes

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, performance-monitoring, performance-counters

(Be gentle with me, I'm a developer, not a server guy)

I'm looking at some issues with custom code I have, and I'm tracking pool usage on a Windows Server 2008 machine.  I'm confused about some performance counters though.

Memory\Pool Paged Bytes on the machine is 400 MB

The description of that counter says:

> Pool Paged Bytes is the size, in bytes, of the paged pool, an area of
>   system memory (physical memory used by the operating system) for
>   objects that can be written to disk when they are not being used. 
>   Memory\Pool Paged Bytes is calculated differently than Process\Pool
>   Paged Bytes, so it might not equal Process\Pool Paged Bytes\_Total.
>   This counter displays the last observed value only; it is not an
>   average.

Process(_Total)\Pool Paged Bytes is 9MB.  The description for that counter says is the same as for Memory\Pool Paged Bytes:

I understand that these values are computed "Differently", but is the size of the difference indicative of any problem?  Does anyone know the difference in how the values are calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem since one is the process and one is the memory used by stale non paged memory see [How do I tell if my Windows server is swapping?](https://serverfault.com/questions/74822/how-do-i-tell-if-my-windows-server-is-swapping/75027#75027)